# How to add 'rake test' to project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

When I ran `rake -`T, I discovered `rake test` was missing.  What do I need to do to get this task in there?  Specifically, I want to run `rake test:benchmark` but that doesn't seem to be loaded.  For example...

```
$rake test:benchmark

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'test:benchmark'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My `config/application.rb` file was missing this line:

```
require 'rails/all'
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need:

`require "rails/test_unit/railtie"`

in your `config/application.rb`